# wsdl2java - how to ignore specific schema in cxf-codegen-plugin and add dependency

Tags: java, maven, wsdl2java, cxf-codegen-plugin

See below, I have 3 projects as mentioned.

```
Common
    Age.xsd (namespace: http://xmlns.common/age)
    generated/common/xmlns/age/AgeType.java
    pom.xml (cxf-xjc-plugin xsdtojava)


Person
    PersonService.wsdl (imports Age.xsd in wsd:types)
    generated/com/person/AgeType.java
    pom.xml (cxf-codegen-plugin wsdl2java)

Animal
    AnimalService.wsdl (imports Age.xsd in wsd:types)
    generated/com/animal/AgeType.java
    pom.xml (cxf-codegen-plugin wsdl2java)
```

Both `AnimalService.wsdl` and `PersonService.wsdl` imports the Age.xsd schema as mentioned below:

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:cn="http://xmlns.common/age"
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import
        namespace="http://xmlns.common/age"
         schemaLocation="classpath:/common/xmlns/age/Age.xsd" />
    </xsd:import>
    </xsd:schema>
     <!-- cn:AgeType used in output message -->
    <!-- ignored -->
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

Question:

How to tell `cxf-codegen wsdl2java` to **do not generate code for** AgeType (which is in  namespace http://xmlns.common/age) and use common.xmlns.age.AgeType instead of com.person.AgeType and com.animal.AgeType in respective projects by supplying the `Common` project as dependency?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer. We need to use `-nexclude` in the `extraarg` as follows with `Common` project dependency added to `Animal` and `Person` project.

```
<wsdlOptions>
 <wsdlOption>
  <wsdl>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/Animal.wsdl</wsdl>
  <wsdlLocation>classpath:Animal.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
  <extraargs>
   <extraarg>-nexclude</extraarg>
   <extraarg>http://xmlns.common/age=common.xmlns.age</extraarg>
  </extraargs>
 </wsdlOption>
</wsdlOptions>
```

The syntax is:

```
<extraarg>-nexlude</extraarg>
<extraarg>namespace to be excluded=package where the JAXB generated classes available</extraarg>
```